# Datatables initialize in a controller php

Tags: php, jquery

I have made an ajax request to get some data from Database and I made a table in the controller but I need to make it a datatable so I can customize it and keep the same UI as other views. I've tried to initialize it in the controller but had no success. Is it possible to do it or I have to initialize it on the view(or js)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('.dataTables-example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            rightColumns: 1
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: are you using laravel ?

Comment: No, im working with a custom mvc.

Comment: Ohk, But you have to write any js related initialization in the view itself not in the controller.

Comment: i have done that, but the table comes as normal <table> and not as a datatable

Comment: Then you should check the browser console to see the errors.
Have you inserted `jQuery` and `datatable` js appropriately or not.

Comment: Plus you have not mentioned any ajax settings into the datatable it self.

Comment: Please see this link to how to get ajax base data into datatable. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Comment: Maybe i didnt explained my self in the correct way. I'm not generating the datatables after the ajax call, im doing it in the ajax controller. And yes i have inserted the links in the controller, and im not getting any console error, the ````<table>```` simply doenst output as a datatable, thats why i was asking if its possible to do it in the controller like im doing.

Comment: You are loading all js in your controller and then when view renders i think the jquery and reintialize so you were never get the table that you want.

Comment: You sure about that? There is no work around it?

Comment: yes @AlexisGarcia

Comment: I figure it out.... And yes there is a work around. Its so simple i dont know why i didnt tryied this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was so simple that i dont even know why i didnt tryied this before (shame).

```
my_function(config).complete(function(){
        $('#TableMap').DataTable({......
```

So easy, hope it helps some one.

Comment: and where it is located ? my_function?